# Non-numeric argument to binary operator, despite values being numeric

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression

In the following code I'm attempting to perform a logistic regression of with a dependent and independent variable, while adjusting for the factors Age and Gender.

```
# Assuming your dataframe is called df
# Make sure your dependent variable is a factor
heart_data$LAV_Over34 <- as.factor(heart_data$LAV_Over34)
heart_data$Age <- as.numeric(heart_data$Age)
heart_data$Gender <- as.numeric(heart_data$Gender)

# Fit logistic regression model adjusted for age and sex (change the variable names if necessary)
logistic_model <- glm(LAV_Over34 ~ HA_nonP_gap, data = heart_data + heart_data$Age + heart_data$Gender, family = "binomial")
summary(logistic_model)$coefficients[, "Estimate"]

# Calculate the 95% confidence intervals for odds ratios
conf_intervals <- confint(logistic_model, level = 0.95)

# Print the confidence intervals
conf_intervals

summary(logistic_model)
```

When running the code, I receive the error saying that I'm using a non-numeric argument.

However, as seen above, I've converted these variables to numerical (previously integers), and when checking the df they show up as numerical (list shortened for convenience):

```
'data.frame':   2896 obs. of  69 variables:
 $ ECG_ID                       : int  62 65 66 68 69 71 74 76 88 89 ...
 $ Index                        : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Age                          : num  40 67 42 71 48 38 66 73 64 39 ...
 $ Gender                       : num  1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Heartage_P                   : num  51 84 47.1 97.7 48.2 ...
 $ HAG_P                        : num  11.04 16.99 5.08 26.7 0.21 ...
 $ HA_nonP                      : num  49.8 57.4 43.6 83.7 47.9 ...
 $ HA_nonP_gap                  : num  9.79 -9.57 1.56 12.72 -0.14 ...
 $ LA_area                      : num  15 28 17 NA 18 25 23 25 24 NA ...
 $ LA_volume                    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 61 NA NA ...
 $ LAV_Over34                   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 2 NA NA ...
```

The error disappears when removing Age and Gender and running it unadjusted, and using other numerical varibles as factors to adjust for also cause the error.

Comment: Weclome to SO! Using `data = heart_data + heart_data$Age + heart_data$Gender`  makes no sense. Doing so you add the value of Age and Gender to *each* column of your dataset, which most likely also includes some non-numeric columns. The `data=` argument is used to pass the dataset containing the variables used in the model. If you want to account for Age and Gender in your model then add it your model formula, e.g. `LAV_Over34 ~ HA_nonP_gap + Age + Gender`.

Comment: I think @stefan has the right fix, though there's very little we can do further: your `LAV_Over34` is all `NA` in the not-very-usable `str()` output, so with stefan's fix I still get `Error: variable 1 has no levels`. The response variable in a regression needs to have non-`NA` values. If you have data that is actually usable, please change your sample data to something more usable, such as `dput(head(heart_data[!is.na(heart_data$LAV_Over34),],20))` into a code block. Thanks!